# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib'

Tags: google-colaboratory

I cannot use edward package on google cola.

### I have the below error:

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 import edward

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/edward/models/dirichlet_process.py in ()
      6 
      7 from edward.models.random_variable import RandomVariable
----> 8 from tensorflow.contrib.distributions import Distribution
      9 
     10 try:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib'

---

NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the

### "Open Examples" button below.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstalling current/latest version of tensorflow and installing version 1.14 resolved it for me. Looks like they removed tensorflow.contrib from tensorflow version >1.14.

```
!pip uninstall tensorflow
!pip install tensorflow==1.14
```